# why does int [][] mat = new int [3][3] and int mat[][] = new int [3][3] doesn't make any difference?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

While initializing an array by

```
int [][] mat = new int [3][3]
```

OR by

```
int mat[][] = new int [3][3]
```

there is no change.

Why it does not make any difference ? is it just Java style to give freedom to a developer or is there any internal functionality change based on how you initialize an 2d array or even a normal array. The question may be very silly but still I want to know about it.

Comment: They are semantically the same, just a choice of syntax really.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-java